# What would be a common way to allow a user to set a profile default photo?

Tags: php, c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, codeigniter

I finished building a photo gallery and would like to give users the ability to set default profile photo and album cover photo from uploaded photos.

I have the following tables in my database:

- User(s) has one profile, has many PhotoAlbums
- Profile(s) belongs to user
- PhotoAlbum(s) belongs to user, has many photos
- Photo(s) belongs to PhotoAlbum

What is a common way this is handled?

Comment: Nice username... let me guess, whatever the end solution ends up being, you'll try lots of other things first and almost kill your photo gallery in the process before pulling off a miraculous save?

Comment: Exactly, you know me well wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to store past profile/album default photo selections, a simple approach would be:

```
profiles.photo_id       -> photos.photo_id
photo_albums.photo_id   -> photos.photo_id
```

In your code you can enforce that the album cover photo is, in fact, in that album.

You'll need to come up with a rule for when the user deletes a photo that's being used as default/cover (perhaps either oldest or newest photo added).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Would you be able to elaborate the above as I'm still quite confused with out to do this. For now I'd have a "set as default" link with each photo. What ever photo is default will have the link replaced with the word default and the rest will still show the link. Easy to do... but what needs to happen in the database when the link is clicked? What I know is I need a way of recording which photo has been set as default. Not sure what should be happening when link is clicked to make sure that happens.

Comment: When the user clicks "set as default" the backend needs to fill `profiles.photo_id` with the `id` of that photo.

Comment: Yep, got it after reading your example a few times. I just need to add  the needed columns to both tables. Very easy solution thanks.